# Implementation WordPress by PhpStorm

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm

A few days ago, in PhpStorm when I've written first letter of a function of WordPress, PhpStorm has suggested many help functions, but nowadays it does not work for me.

I've used invalidate cashes option but it has not fixed; installed PhpStorm again but it does not suggest for me WordPress functions.

What should I do in order to fix of this issue?

Comment: Did you check in preference -> languages & frameworks -> php -> framewors? there yuo can insert the root from your local installation

Comment: Yes, but this way responses in the first day, after that there are issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following instructions:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html

Comment: I've done it, but on the first day it is true after that no